# exports is not defined in Typescript

Tags: jquery, typescript

I add JQuery in Typescript but I have this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Code TS:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'

  $('.test').click(function(eventObject){
      alert('med');
  })
```

code js:

```
"use strict";
 exports.__esModule = true;
var $ = require("jquery");
$('.test').click(function (eventObject) {
    alert('med');
});
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "es6",
        "pretty": true,
        "experimentalDecorators":true
    },

    "files": [
        "demo.ts",
        "typings/index.d.ts"
    ],

    "excluse": ["node_modules"]
}
```

how to resolve this bug ?

Comment: Can you post your tsconfig file?

Comment: And where do you get this error?

Comment: And do you have the `@types/jquery` and `jquery` npm packages installed?

Comment: @rgvassar , I update my question when I add code tsconfig

Comment: @unional , I have this error in console ( in code js )

Comment: Are you loading it on browser? That code is not to be run directly on browser

Comment: yes I loading it in browser and I have this bug :  Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Comment: any friend for help me please ...

Comment: You have a typo in your tsconfig `"excluse": ["node_modules"]`

Answer (score 1):

have you tried with...

```
declare var $ :any


  $('.test').click(function(eventObject){
      alert('med');
  })
```

Comment: error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable '$'.

Comment: @devit2017 Frederico means to use this _instead_ of your `import` statement, and to include jQuery in your global scripts so it's available on the `window`. I assume (it's a common pattern).

Comment: @devit2017 I was merely expanding on the answer given your error message. It's not the way I would solve the problem, buy I don't have an immediate solution, so I didn't write an answer. I'm also struggling with jQuery in an ng 4 app with angular cli...

Comment: @msanford , I add declare var $ :any but I have this bug :  
error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable '$'

Comment: can you post ALL you class?